# Pycharm not giving recommendations

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with the 'OpenCV' python library.
after `cv2.` pycharm does not suggest methods like imread,imshow and...

While the Methods are well suggested for other libraries

[image: 1]

Why's this happening?

Comment: PyCharm may also have some bugs. Maybe you should rather ask on [PyCharm` forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm)

Comment: Did you installed cv2 on project environment? Note: some high dynamic libraries are very difficult to parse and predict completition

Comment: Yes I installed it in a virtual environment